# Visual Studio 2013 CSS/JS Remote Publish Issue

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-2013

Is there any reason why a Visual Studio 2013 Project which is error free and works perfectly locally would not render some CSS and JS files remotely?

I have checked the remote host and all files/folders have copied successfully and the pages work but the Site.css does not appear to be rendering correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: What's the problem? What happens?

Comment: CSS tags such as ul, li, span-6, etc.. are not rendering, nor is the bootstrap firing. Everything works and renders perfectly locally.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: In the developer tools.

Comment: I cant see them anywhere, gone through all the menu options.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51976/discussion-between-iggyweb-and-slaks)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution to my problem, I ensured Release was select in Solution Configurations then removed all files from Content and Scripts folders. Then for each of the Content and Scripts folders I added back the existing items.

I then clicked Clean WebApplication1 followed by Build WebApplications1, ran the project through Internet Explorer and Firefox just to make sure everything was still functioning and displaying normally locally, which it was so then clicked Publish WebApplication1 and under Settings I selected Release and ticked Delete all existing files prior to publish.

All CSS and JS render perfectly both locally and remotely now.

I hope this solution proves useful to others :-)